# authentication error on simulator : Xcode7

Tags: authentication, xcode7, simulator

I have an application that gives an authentication error when I run it on Simulator but works fine on IPad. While debugging , i found that the credentials fail to match on simulator. (I connect simulator and the IPad to the same network while testing.) Does anybody know why this could happen?

Comment: reset settings - Settings->General->Reset->Reset All Settings.

Comment: the issue is with only this application. So i dont think it would solve my prob